# Shell Script - Auto Increment directory version not working as expected

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have written a shell script that is supposed to auto-increment the version(major, minor, patch) and create the new directory accordingly. The script takes 4 user inputs as parameters - `version_type(major, minor, patch), build_number, git_branch, build_purpose`. The format of the versioned directory that this script should return as output is - `<git-branch>_<build-purpose>_<build-number>_<X.X.X.RELEASE>`

My script is not working as expected, I think, I am making some small mistakes. The above script is changing the major, minor, and patch version fields only one time. Suppose I want to create a directory for a major version and already some directory exists for the major versions then the script should check the past major versioned directories and auto-increment the major version part of the directory name based on the latest/last created major versioned directory. Similarly for minor and patch versions.

Let me explain to you a bit more with a few more examples -

**Input** - sh versionedDirCreator.sh major 1 dev kafka **Output** - kafka_dev_1_1.0.0.RELEASE

**Input** - sh versionedDirCreator.sh minor 2 dev kafka **Output** - kafka_dev_2_1.1.0.RELEASE

**Input** - sh versionedDirCreator.sh patch 3 dev kafka **Output** - kafka_dev_3_1.1.1.RELEASE

**Input** - sh versionedDirCreator.sh patch 4 dev kafka **Output** - kafka_dev_4_1.1.2.RELEASE

**Input** - sh versionedDirCreator.sh minor 5 dev kafka **Output** - kafka_dev_5_1.2.0.RELEASE

**Input** - sh versionedDirCreator.sh minor 6 dev kafka **Output** - kafka_dev_6_1.3.0.RELEASE

**Input** - sh versionedDirCreator.sh patch 7 dev kafka **Output** - kafka_dev_7_1.3.1.RELEASE

**Input** - sh versionedDirCreator.sh major 8 dev kafka **Output** - kafka_dev_8_2.0.0.RELEASE

**Input** - sh versionedDirCreator.sh major 9 dev kafka **Output** - kafka_dev_9_3.0.0.RELEASE

**Input** - sh versionedDirCreator.sh minor 10 dev kafka **Output** - kafka_dev_10_3.1.0.RELEASE

**Input** - sh versionedDirCreator.sh patch 11 dev kafka **Output** - kafka_dev_11_3.1.1.RELEASE

and so on.
It should work for all similar inputs.

My script-

```
#!/bin/bash

#function to increment the version field based on version type
increment_version() {
    local version=$1
    local version_type=$2

    # split version into major, minor, and patch
    local major=$(echo $version | cut -d '.' -f 1)
    local minor=$(echo $version | cut -d '.' -f 2)
    local patch=$(echo $version | cut -d '.' -f 3)

    # increment version field based on version type
    if [ $version_type = "major" ]; then
        ((major++))
        minor=0
        patch=0
    elif [ $version_type = "minor" ]; then
        ((minor++))
        patch=0
    elif [ $version_type = "patch" ]; then
        ((patch++))
    fi

    # return incremented version
    echo "$major.$minor.$patch.RELEASE"
}

# get user input for version type, build number, git branch, and build purpose
if [ $# -lt 4 ]; then
    echo "Usage: $0 version_type build_number git_branch build_purpose"
    exit 1
fi

version_type=$1
build_number=$2
git_branch=$3
build_purpose=$4

# check if any versioned directory exists
latest_versioned_dir=$(ls -d */ 2>/dev/null | grep -E '^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.RELEASE/$' | sort -Vr | head -n1)

if [ -z "$latest_versioned_dir" ]; then
    # no versioned directory exists, create initial directory
    new_version=$(increment_version "0.0.0.RELEASE" "$version_type")
else
    # get the latest versioned directory
    latest_version=$(basename "$latest_versioned_dir" | sed 's/\.RELEASE//')

    # increment the appropriate version field based on version type
    new_version=$(increment_version "$latest_version" "$version_type")
fi

# append git_branch, build_purpose, and build_number to the new version
new_version="${git_branch}_${build_purpose}_${build_number}_${new_version}"

# create new versioned directory
if [ -d "$new_version" ]; then
    echo "Directory $new_version already exists"
else
    mkdir "$new_version"
    echo "$new_version"
fi
```

Can someone please help to get the desired output from this script? Thanks in advance.

Comment: At the very least, give one concrete example input for `increment_version`, where it produces an unexpected result, and state what result you would get, and what you had expected. BTW, you can do most of the debugging by yourself, if you run your program with `set -x` turned on. This allows you at least to see at which point the wrong results have been produced.

Comment: Why does `"Input - sh versionedDirCreator.sh minor 2 dev kafka Output - kafka_dev_2_1.1.0.RELEASE"` look like a major rel change?

Comment: Why are you specifying the `<build-number>` as argument of the command? shouldn't it be incremented automatically?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin The script should check the last major version and create the minor versioned directory considering the latest major version. So here, since it will major 1 major versioned directory is already present, so it will update the minor version field of the directory.

Comment: @Fravadona Yes, I am calling this script from a Jenkins pipeline so it will come from there. I am feeding <build-bumber> as one of the parameter from that pipeline.

Comment: I see now, the `1.1.0.RELEASE` is the traditional `major.minor.patch`, the `...DEV_2` was the confusing part.

Comment: Instead of multiple `echo | cut` calls, just write `IFS=. read major minor patch <<< $version`